# sort data by a column in getCsvFile()

Tags: magento-1.9, sales, csv, grid

i am using this following code to export my grid:

```
/**
* Export order grid to CSV format
*/
public function exportCsvAction()
{
   $fileName   = 'orders.csv';
   $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_grid');
   $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}
```

how do i sort the exported data by specific column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid class, please check it, you may find some useful things there :)

```
/**
 * Add column view order
 *
 * @param string $columnId
 * @param string $after
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 */
public function addColumnsOrder($columnId, $after)
{
    $this->_columnsOrder[$columnId] = $after;
    return $this;
}
```